# How to display latest posted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have an app that allows users to upload songs and vote them up. The songs with the higher vote count end up on top, and the newly posted songs need to be voted up to be seen (think hackernews).

I also have a 'new songs' page that I'd like to display the newly uploaded songs first negating the votes (alas hackernews)

My current song_controller sorts the songs in the index as such:

```
def index
    @songs = Song.order('plusminus')
  end
```

I have a def new_songs action in the song_controller but I'm not sure how to have it display just the new songs and bypass the [thumbs up gem](https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up) voting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about that gem, but it seems to be scope based. How about just querying the data normally?

```
def new_songs
  @songs = Song.order "id DESC"
end
```

or better, write your own scope:

```
# song.rb

scope :newest, order("id DESC")

# song_controller.rb

def new_songs
  @songs = Song.newest
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass an instance variable containing the most recently uploaded songs from your controller action to the view:

```
# app/controllers/songs_controller.rb
def index
    @songs = Song.order('plusminus')
    @newest_songs = Song.order('created_at DESC').limit(10) # returns the ten most recently uploaded songs
end
```

In the view, you'll have access to the ten most newest songs via the `@newest_songs` instance variable:

```
# app/views/songs/index.html.erb
<h1>Highest Voted Songs</h1>
<% @songs.each do |song| %>
    # view logic
<% end %>

<h1>Newest Songs</h1>
<% @newest_songs.each do |song| %>
    # view logic
<% end %>
```

**Alternatively**, if you want to display the newest songs via an entirely separate view, you could do something akin to the following:

```
# app/controllers/songs_controller.rb
def new_songs
    @songs = Song.order('created_at DESC')
end

# app/views/songs/new_songs.html.erb
<h1>Newest Songs</h1>
<% @newest_songs.each do |song| %>
    # view logic
<% end %>

# config/routes.rb
resources :songs do
    collection do
        get 'new_songs' # creates route from `songs/new_songs` to the `songs#new_songs` controller action
    end
end
```